# Compare 3>&2 and 3<&2?

Tags: shell, io-redirection

Are the redirections 3>&2 and 3<&2 different?

What are the differences?

Is it only that in 3>&2 should raise an error as `2` is not open for input?

Compare:

```
{ seq 20 1<&2; } 2>/dev/null

{ seq 20 1>&2; } 2>/dev/null
```

EDIT: answer

Both the commands execute the same duplication of 1 and 2.
The output of this:

```
$ strace -f -e trace=dup,dup2 -o o2 sh -c 'seq 20 1>&2'
```

is exactly equal (beside PID numbers) for both commands.

Comment: See also [What does “sh a.sh <&0 >&0” mean?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/84620)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I already understood that `<&0` affects stdin only and that `>&0` affects std**out**, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Why the downvote? What is wrong in asking a question that has never been asked before?

Comment: no idea. Not mine.

Comment: No @StéphaneChazelas it was not directed to you, sorry for the noise. I just hope that the comment could be directed to the user down voting. In any case, please, you never mind, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they're strictly equivalent, the shell ends up doing `dup2(2, 3)` for both `3>&2` and `3<&2`. The fd `3` then ends up pointing to the same *open file description* as on fd 2. It has no influence on the mode/direction of that *open file description*. It is not possible to change  the  mode/direction of an open  file description.

The `x>&y` and `x<&y` operators are only different when `x` is omitted. `>&y` is `1>&y` (same as `1<&y`) while `<&y`  is `0<&y` (same as `0>&y`).

Comment: This is what I already mentioned: the final redirection creates a writable file descriptor.

Answer (score 2):

One redirects stderr for output and the other for input.

If you like to have stderr open for reading and writing, you could use:

```
2<>/dev/null
```

If you log in, all three file descriptors are open for reading and writing.

This is done by first opening the tty and then calling `dup()` 2 times.

The commands

```
{ seq 20 1<&2; } 2>/dev/null
```

and

```
{ seq 20 1>&2; } 2>/dev/null
```

are equivalent because the final redirection creates a file descriptor that is open for writing.

If you call:

```
{ truss -o o seq 20 1<&2; } 2>/dev/null
```

you will see that the write call from `seq` succeeds, And BTW: the output from `seq` goes to /dev/null

Comment: What? You’re answering a question about non-standard behaviour? ;-)

Comment: Well, `<>` is in the Bourne Shell since at least 35 years ;-) See POSIX 2.7.7

Comment: Re-read the question (it changed). Why both `{ seq 20 1<&2; } 2>/dev/null` and `{ seq 20 1>&2; } 2>/dev/null` seem to do the same ?

Comment: I do not believe that this answer is the whole description. Where is the output of `seq` going to?  To `&2` in both cases ?

Comment: See the edit I did on the answer just before you wrote this comment: the final redirection creates the right descriptor.

Comment: There's no such thing as a `3<>&2` operator. The `x>&y` and `x<&y` only duplicate file descriptors (get a new fd to the same open file description), they have no influence on the mode of that open file description.

Comment: `<>` was in Bourne shell from the start (not documented) but was initially broken. Fixed first in Solaris 2.6 (20 years ago) according to https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/bourne/